# How to control the xml element label generated by xstream?

Tags: xml, restlet

I use xstream to convert object to xml.

```
public class XXXInfo
{
    private String id;

    private String name;

    private YYYInfo yyy;
}
```

the member variable's name is correctly written to xml file.

but the element label for the outermost layer of the xml comes with a prefix of my package name.

How to modify it to what I want it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the annotation to control this.

```
@XStreamAlias("names you want")
public class XXXInfo
{
    private String id;

    private String name;

    private YYYInfo yyy;
}
```

and then remember to call the `XStream.processAnnotations(XXXInfo.class)` to make it effect.

or you can also call the `XStream.autodetectAnnotations(true)` to enable the annotation detection function.

Good Luck!

Comment: Alternatively you can use the [alias method](http://xstream.codehaus.org/javadoc/com/thoughtworks/xstream/XStream.html#alias(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class)) on the `XStream` object to register aliases, but I personally prefer annotations as it keeps the alias definition together with the class it is aliasing.  However this is a useful alternative to know when you're working with third party classes you can't modify.